# Error in self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

Tags: python, pygame

Help, an error occurs when compiling:

The error occurs here `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`

> ```
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_rect'
> ```

[image]

```py
class GameSprite(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, speed, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.speed = speed
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the error trace in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image` is a filename. You need to load the image from the file with [`pygame.image.load`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load):

```py
class GameSprite(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, filename, speed, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image.load(filename)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
        self.speed = speed
```

However, I recommend to `import pygame` instead of `from pygame import *`:

```py
import pygame

class GameSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, filename, speed, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
        self.speed = speed
```